# JavaScript bencode binary length

Tags: javascript, file, binary

I'm trying to decode a torrent file in JavaScript and the length is not good.

```
path = "file.torrent";
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);
    }
});
```

I did the same thing in PHP and the length are differents.

```
$f=file_get_contents($filename, FILE_BINARY);
var_dump(strlen($f));
```

I think the ajax method don't return binary file.

How can I get some thing similar that file_get_contents($filename, FILE_BINARY) in JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript does not do very well with binary data. You can't handle it at all unless you have a modern browser/js engine.

Comment: I shall venture a guess: serve it with a `Content-Type` of `application/octet-stream`, if you haven’t already.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `processData` switch to false:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);
    }
});
```

Now jQuery won't try to be intelligent and automatically parse the data based on the Content-Type response header returned by your server but it will pass it to the success callback as raw data. Obviously dealing with binary data in javascript is not something that this language has been designed for. With HTML5 there have been some nice additions though.

Also it's worth mentioning that calling `.length` on some binary data that you have received from the server might not make much sense and chances are you would get a javascript error because this property is not defined.

Comment: I add processData: false but the length still wrong how can I get it rigth? because I need length to check if the file integrity is ok

Comment: But is there even a `length` property on the `data` instance? Have you tried logging the data to the console? How does it look like?

Comment: It look like a string but one part is binary as describe here http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification